# Problem running drive.file.list api script when spreadsheet-ui modal dialog with html is working

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, drive, google-workspace

At first I was running it on drive app, it works perfectly, then I try to migrate to the api and I run with a problem when I run this in the UI with HTML the program does not work, yet if I run the same script in the editor by selecting the function and debugging it works, I believe that the problem is that I have to do something with the api permission, because I'm running it at web browser when I use the UI with HTML but I don't know what to do

I tried to create a project in the google api console, but I have no response either.

```
//html
function fillData() {
    var folderId = document.getElementById("ingress").value;
    document.getElementById("branch").innerHTML = "branch #" + (++branch);
    google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(newRun)
        .withFailureHandler(error)
        .fillData(folderId, 25,true);
}

//code.gs

function fillData(folderId, max, API) {
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
    var data = (API) ? API(folderId, max) :APP(folderId, max);
    var lastRow= getLastRow_(hojaAuditoria.getRange("A4:A"), 4);
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length);
    dataRange.setValues(data);
    var timeStamp = new Date();
    sheet.getRange("B3")
        .setValue(timeStamp)
        .setHorizontalAlignment('left')
        .setFontWeight("normal")
        .setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    return (PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("token") != null);
}

function API(folderId, max) {
    max= (max === undefined) ? max= 100 : max;
    var pageToken = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("token");
    var strAux = (folderId === undefined) ? "" : 'and "' + folderId + '" in parents';
    var query = 'mimeType != "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"' + strAux;
    var files;
    var result = [];
    files = Drive.Files.list({
        q: query,
        maxResults: max,
        pageToken: pageToken,
        includeRemoved: true,
        spaces: 'drive'
    });
    if (files.items && files.items.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.items.length; i++) {
            var file = files.items[i];
            var fileAux = DriveApp.getFileById(file.id);
            SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(file.title, "audit");
            var permissions = getPermissions(file.id);
            var parents = getParentData(file.parents);
            result[i] = [
                file.id,
                "=HYPERLINK(\"" + file.alternateLink + "\";\"" + file.title + "\")",
                file.mimeType,
                date(new Date(file.createdDate)),
                date(new Date(file.modifiedDate)),
                (file.fileSize === undefined) ? "" : file.fileSize,
                parents[0],
                parents[1],
                parents[2],
                (file.labels.trashed) ? "YES" : "NO",
                fileAux.getSharingAccess(),
                fileAux.getSharingPermission(),
                permissions[0],
                permissions[1],
                permissions[2],
                permissions[3]
            ];
        }
    } else {
        Logger.log('No files found.');
    }
    pageToken = files.nextPageToken;
    PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty("token", pageToken);
    return result;
}
```

i use the API flag in fillData function to change from driveApp to API i got perfectly working UI with HTML surprisingly it work in the api too if i running it by the debugging provided by the google script editor but when i running the API with the UI whith HTML i got this error

ReferenceError: "Drive" is not defined. at API(Permissions_Audit:26) at fillData(sheetAudit:62)

Comment: It seems that you are using Drive API of Advanced Google Services. So can you confirm whether Drive API is enabled at Advanced Google Services, again? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced

Comment: yes it is enabled

Comment: Can I ask you about the error line?

Comment: sure, what about?

Comment: Can you show the script of the line that the error occurs?

Comment: files = Drive.Files.list({
        q: query,
        maxResults: max,
        pageToken: pageToken,
        includeRemoved: true,
        spaces: 'drive'
    }); this is the line that presents the error

Comment: the function is in the question, its API()

Comment: Thank you for providing it. The error of ``"Drive" is not defined`` occurs at there, even if Drive API is enabled at Advanced Google Services. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes it is correct, but only if i running the script by HTML in the UI dialog modal cuz when i running it in the editor it works perfectly

Comment: For example, how about directly requesting the endpoint of Drive API without using Advanced Google Services?

Comment: it does not work neither

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comments were not useful for your situation.

Comment: well, it in fact work again, if i running it in the editor, but when i runnin it, in the UI with HTML still said that the Drive is not defined